# Chromium crashes after reinstallation on pi4

Tags: raspberry-pi-os, chromium, debug

I noticed, today, that pages weren't loading in chromium, but If I pinged them in bash, using `ping google.com`, it went through just fine.
So, I reinstalled chromium, but, now a different problem has arised.
When I click on the chromium icon, under the start menu, the chromium window opens for a very short time, then crashes.
This is the error I get now, when I try to open chromium in the terminal. What can I do to fix it?

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ chromium
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[2441:2441:0509/154448.709721:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(972)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=6
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[2441:2441:0509/154448.821820:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(972)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=6
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[2441:2441:0509/154448.863289:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(972)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=6
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[2441:2441:0509/154448.877337:ERROR:system_web_app_manager.cc(320)] Exceeded SWA install retry attempts.  Skipping installation, will retry on next OS update or when locale changes.
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[2441:2441:0509/154448.910701:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(972)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=6
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[2441:2441:0509/154448.945295:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(972)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=6
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
*** stack smashing detected ***: terminated
[2441:2441:0509/154448.964279:ERROR:gpu_process_host.cc(972)] GPU process exited unexpectedly: exit_code=6
[2441:2441:0509/154448.964358:FATAL:gpu_data_manager_impl_private.cc(447)] GPU process isn't usable. Goodbye.
[0509/154448.976847:ERROR:elf_dynamic_array_reader.h(64)] tag not found
Trace/breakpoint trap
pi@raspberrypi:~ $
```

UPDATE: I reinstalled Chromium, using [Botspot's Pi-Apps](https://github.com/botspot/pi-apps), and now, I'm surfing the web like nothing ever happened. Yay!

Comment: Which version of the operating system ? Which version of chromium ? Also try  chromium-browser as an alternative to chromium.

Comment: Sorry, but I fixed the problem, already. Please read my edit.